# tlp command to execute full battery charge and then reset to configured settings without reboot?

Tags: command-line, battery, tlp

I have my Thinkpad laptop configured to charge up to 80% cause I mostly use it on AC. On the occasional use where I am taking it off AC, is there a command that basically tells tlp to charge the battery to 100% and once 100% is reached, return charging behavior to the 80% configuration?

I see there is command `sudo tlp fullcharge [ BAT0 | BAT1 ]`, but this command requires a reboot before the "80%" configuration is restored. Is there a command to restore the "80%" configuration without having to reboot?

Answer (score 8):

Of course. It's

```
tlp setcharge
```

For convenience you may also configure

```
RESTORE_THRESHOLDS_ON_BAT=1
```

Then the thresholds will be re-applied automatically when you disconnect the charger.

https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/battery.html#restore-thresholds-on-bat

Comment: To be clear [tlp fullcharge](https://linrunner.de/tlp/usage/tlp.html) even says that you can use `tlp setcharge` without further arguments for resetting to your configured values

Comment: Yet, as OP said, setting charge criteria requires reboot by default. linrunner explains that one may use `RESTORE_THRESHOLD_ON_BAT=1` to be able to, instead, unplug and plug power to apply the set charge.